# TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalresults' of null (localStorage)

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am currently trying to implement localStorage into my project for the first time, I have gotten to grips with most of it but when my project is first loaded up in browser and localStorage is empty I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalresults' of null (localStorage)
```

I know this is because the project is trying to read from localStorage and output to the project, how would I avoid this?

**My Code**

```
export default class QuizPage extends Component {

    state = {
        results: 0,
        currentCourse:null,
        totalResults: "",
        percentage: "",
        passed: "",
        answered: 0,
        disabled: true,
        courses: []
    }


    componentDidMount(){

        // Read results from localStorage

        const courseResults = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.props.match.params.course))

        this.setState({
          currentCourse: courseID,
          totalResults: courseResults.totalresults,
          results: courseResults.results,
          passed: courseResults.passed.toLowerCase()
        })

      );


componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

       // Save current results to localStorage

        const course = {
          result: this.state.results,
          passed: this.state.passed,
          totalresults: this.state.totalResults,
          coursename: this.state.courseName
        }

        localStorage.setItem(this.props.match.params.course, JSON.stringify(course))


      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first time if there's nothing in the local storage then

```
const courseResults = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.props.match.params.course))
```

will be null.

So before using `courseResults` make sure that it is a truthy value:

```
componentDidMount() {

    const courseResults = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.props.match.params.course))

    if (courseResults) {
        this.setState({
          currentCourse: courseID,
          totalResults: courseResults.totalresults,
          results: courseResults.results,
          passed: courseResults.passed.toLowerCase()
        })
    }

};
```